# How to get "Shared with me" files in google drive via API?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I think that I should use [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request with "q" parameter. I don't know which value of q parameter I should to set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this you can give the value in `q` parameter. In this you can verify with the `sharedWithMe` field. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#operators) document for reference.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is it possible to search for files 'not' sharedWithMe?

Comment: @JayIsTooCommon: Yes, `sharedWithMe` is a boolean, so you can query for true or false.  See query fields for `files.list` at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

Answer (score 2):

`sharedWithMe` still works with v3 API, but the problem with it is that it only returns the root shared files or folders. So if someone has shared their folder with you, you only receive that folder - not its contents - with `sharedWithMe = true` query.

I found using `"not 'me' in owners"` with the default `user` corpora much better as it returns all files that you don't own which, as it happens, are by definition what the `Shared with me` files are. If you owned it, it would reside inside your drive.

EDIT: There's a nasty bug here you can trip on like I did. By default `includeItemsFromAllDrives` is set to `false` and it works when fetching `Shared With Me` files. However, if you want to fetch files from Shared Drives as well, you have to use `includeItemsFromAllDrives = true` in order to do so. If you forget to explicitly set it back to `includeItemsFromAllDrives = false` when fetching `Shared With Me` files you'll be refetching the same contents as in the Shared Drives. So be aware.

Comment: An alternative is `-owner:me` in `q`.

Comment: Thank you, THANK YOU kind stranger (for the edit!). This took way too much of my time to figure out.