# Need help finding files in shared drives with C++

Tags: c++, google-drive-api, shared

I'm very experienced with C++ but clueless with the Google API.  Existing code is using the API to find files in drives, but for some reason doesn't find or search shared drives.

I've been able to use GET with /drive/v3/drives? and a few other things to find the shared drives, but when I try to find the files in them, nothing is returned.  I need a patient person to give me a kick in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend backing up your code and carving it down to a [mre] to include in the question. Normally making the MRE would lead you to finding the mistake, but in this case it's going to serve as an example of what you have and what you know so that potential answers can build on it rather that having to start at the  answerer's favorite creation myth and work their way forward

Comment: Apart from your experience with C++, how is this question related? I would rather start sending some hand-carved requests using curl or similar.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean how is this question related.  Related to what?  The code is C++ and the question is how to list file in a shared drive.  I can't find a C++ example anywhere

Comment: This is the string being passed in, modified slightly to protect privacy
GET /drive/v2/files?maxResults=100&orderBy=folder,title&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&q='0AGM88ZPnUl-7Uk9PVA'%20in%20parents%20AND%20'sa.gsuiteqa@spiriondev.net'%20in%20owners&fields=nextPageToken,items(mimeType,id,originalFilename,createdDate,modifiedDate,lastModifyingUser/displayName,explicitlyTrashed,fileSize,title,owners(emailAddress)) HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ya29.sXh_CmRWkzdfQGm082vkXycs2WQRG0J73zWBR7cUpVl4pr3kjoWKHVGNk3n5tPe3smwA-2JFvdL9oHsqZCZbryJdfsfsC-qMsjcuoVKljTBOOpgDyzxUu3pUn8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get "Shared with me" files in google drive via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500889/how-to-get-shared-with-me-files-in-google-drive-via-api)

Comment: I don't see any C++ code, this is why I asked about the relationship to C++.